# how can I find out the id ands value of jQuery timepicker?

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I'm using timepicker to set the start and end time for a series of events, so each timepicker looks like this, where $dateid is a unique variable.

```
<input type='text' class='editable' id='StartTime_$dateid' name='StartTime_$dateid' value='".$row['StartTime']."' readonly />
```

when the timepicker is changed, I trigger an event like so

```
$("ul [id^='StartTime_']").timepicker({ 
   timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
   interval: 15,
   minTime: '5:00am',
   maxTime: '10:00pm',
   startTime: '5:00',
   dynamic: false,
   dropdown: true,
   scrollbar: true,
   change: function( selected ) {
      saveTime(id, selected);
   }
});
```

and this will preform the desired save function

```
function saveTime(id,selected){
  console.log('saveTime fired id '+ id + ' v '+ selected); 
}
```

The problem I am having is getting at the ID and the Value which I need to autosave when the users change values.

I'm getting either "undefined" or some rather long representation of the time like this

saveTime id undefined v Sun Dec 31 1899 05:15:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Value here should be 5:15 AM, which is what user sees in dropdown. If I swap out id and selected for this.id and this.value also returns *undefined* in console log.

Not seeing much in the timepicker docs to explain how to solve this

Comment: Where does the id variable come from?

Comment: its an auto-increment value from the mysql table

Comment: Ok but how are you creating the id variable in your script

Comment: A mysql select statement generates the rows, $dateid is the autoincrement value assigned to the row, and once $dateid is set, I concatenate the string 'StartTime_' with $dateid - the issue is accessing the timepicker id and the value (5 am 6 am etc) when the timepicker changes

Comment: Can you create snippets and share?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(this)` variable inside the change function to get the element, then you can get id by using `$(this).id`. hope this helps